# discord.py how add role to member

Tags: discord.py, roles, member

I cannot solve the problem. How to add a role to the user who called the !role command.
Please, help.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from apex_legends import ApexLegends
```

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = intents)

@client.command()
async def rank(ctx, user_name,):
    rank = get_apex_rank(user_name) #return str role name
    await ctx.send(f"{rank}")# successfully receiving a response from the bot 
    member = ctx.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name=rank)
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

```py
def get_apex_rank(name):
    try:
        player = apex.player(name)
        a = player.__dict__
        return a['_data']['metadata']["rankName"]
    except:
        return "Wrong name"
```

Comment: Can you also please add the `get_apex_range` function.

Comment: also, are you invoking the command in dm's?

Comment: please edit the question, don't post it in the comments, it's impossible to read

Comment: also you didn't answer my second question, are you using the command in dm's? And have you enable `intents.members`?

Comment: i invoking the command in discord, and I can see the I get str "rank" = Bronze 4. And have you enable intents.members? - no

Comment: do you have `intents.members` enabled.

Comment: intents.members is enabled now. Thx tou @Łukasz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@client.command():
async def role(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="enter role name") #enter role name here
    user = ctx.message.author
    await user.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27780780)